# Visualize tensorboard logs for a job running on Azure ml

Tags: azure, tensorboard

I have a training job running on azure ml. The job is submitted using azure cli. In the job.yaml I configured tensorboard service as specified in the following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-interactive-jobs?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=azurecli

In order to get tensorboard link, I run following command

az ml job show-services --name my_job_name --resource-group my_resource_grp --workspace_name my_workspace_name

It returns a json response with link to tensorboard. However, if I follow the link no logs are shown.

Am I doing something wrong?